# How do I rotate a GameObject with a RigidBody based on it's movement direction? Unity | 3D | C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

The title says it all with my question. I am firing a projectile, for sake of ease lets call it an arrow, I'd like it to rotate so that the arrowhead is always pointing in the direction of movement. So for example: if it's fired straight up it would be pointing up & when coming back down it would be facing down.

I have searched up this question & found many different solutions, none of which have worked for me. A big one I see a lot is:

> transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rigidbody.velocity);

and this does rotate the GameObject correctly, however has weird game-breaking consequences where the game object moves slowly, jitters a lot, teleports around, then breaks completely. I have tried putting this code in the Update() function, FixedUpdate() function & the LateUpdate() function all producing the same results.

https://youtu.be/L9LVM8AmjJM - link to a video showing the weird results using the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.LookRotation(rigidbody.velocity));
```

within `FixedUpdate`.

Going through `transform` in most cases breaks the physics and [`MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) interpolates the rotation rather than hard jumping to it and still respects obstacles etc and interacts correctly with those.

---

What happens in your video though I think is that your velocity suddenly changes when hitting the ground -> you hard set the objects rotation -> it is kicked up into the air again because of the resulting collision forces.

This might of course still occure with the upper method => I would skip the rotation setting if colliding with something e.g.

```
int collisions;

private void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    collisions++;
}

private void OnCollisionExit()
{
    collisions--;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(collisions==0) rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.LookRotation(rigidbody.velocity));
}
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly thank you so much, I did not need to include the bottom code, thank you for providing it nevertheless, as I plan on freezing the projectile once it hits something.